# column title of wxListCtrl loaded from XRC file - wxRuby

Tags: ruby, wxwidgets, listctrl, wxruby, xrc

I have problem with loading column title for wxListCtrl which are
defined in xrc file. According to XRC file format description
(http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_xrcformat...)
it shall be possible to define column names for wxLC_REPORT style for
this control by  class. Below you can find code which I need
to run (gui.xml is a xrc file with desired layout). Unfortunately in my
script I need to add column title manually so they are shown in GUI
(commented lines 22, 23 in my_gui.rb). Is there a way to force wxRuby to
load  column titles from xrc or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32] with wxruby-ruby19
(2.0.1 x86-mingw32).

here is my_gui.rb:

```
require 'wx'


class My_frame < Wx::Frame
    def initialize(parent)
        # To load a layout defined in XRC into a Ruby subclass of Dialog,
        # first call the empty constructor. All the details of size,
        # title, position and so on are loaded from the XRC by the call to 
        # load_frame_subclass. Using a non-empty constructor will cause
        # errors on GTK.
        super()

        # Load the dialog from XRC. We define $xml in on_init.
        # We could use XmlResource.get() over and over again, but
        # honestly, thats just too much work.
        $xml.load_frame_subclass(self, nil, 'Gui')
        @list_ctrl = find_window_by_name('MY_LIST')
        puts "inspect list: " + @list_ctrl.inspect + " ID: " +  Wx::xrcid('MY_LIST').to_s

        #columnn names are shown only if you uncomment following 2 lines
#       @list_ctrl.insert_column(0, 'col1_from_code', Wx::LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, 100)
#       @list_ctrl.insert_column(1, 'col2_from_code', Wx::LIST_FORMAT_LEFT, 100)

    end
end

class My_app < Wx::App
    def on_init
        #create GUI from xrc
        xrc_file = File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), 'gui.xml' )
        $xml = Wx::XmlResource.new(xrc_file)
        @frame = My_frame.new(self)
        @frame.show(true)
    end
end

app = My_app.new
app.main_loop()
```

and here is gui.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource version="2.3.0.1">
<!-- Created by  build 7.4.2.569 -->
<object class="wxFrame" name="Gui">
<title>GUI</title>
<IDident>ID_MAIN_FRM</IDident>
<ID>1000</ID>
<pos>8,8</pos>
<size>640,480</size>
<style>wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE</style>
    <object class="wxStaticBox" name="MY_SBOX">
    <IDident>ID_MY_SBOX</IDident>
    <ID>1005</ID>
    <size>610,320</size>
    <pos>5,120</pos>
    <label>Label</label>
    </object>
    <object class="wxListCtrl" name="MY_LIST">
    <IDident>ID_MY_LIST</IDident>
    <ID>1008</ID>
    <size>590,120</size>
    <pos>15,270</pos>
    <style>wxLC_REPORT</style>
        <object class="listcol">
        <text>Col1</text>
        <width>100</width>
        <align>wxLIST_FORMAT_LEFT</align>
        </object>
        <object class="listcol">
        <text>Col2</text>
        <width>100</width>
        <align>wxLIST_FORMAT_LEFT</align>
        </object>
    </object>
</object>
</resource>
```

Thx in advance for support.

Comment: If you use wxWidgets 2.9.3+, this ought to work. But I don't know which version of wx does your version of wxRuby correspond to.

Comment: This is the case.  If I print out const Wx::WXWIDGETS_VERSION in my ruby script it says "2.8.10".